# how to pass button reference activity to adapter android

Tags: java, android

i'll create one activity.

- In activity i'll take one Recyclerview and one Button.
- 2nd i'll create one `.xml` for Recyclerview `ROW`. and in this row i'll take Cardview, TextView, CheckBox, Image etc.

Now i'll create one `adapter.class` in this adapter declare checkbox and image 
and initialize two widgets.

Now i want to if checkbox is check then button can `visible`. and if checkbox is unchecked then button is `gone`

for this i'll try below code in `adapter.class`:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

But the problem is `btnDownload` is null object reference error can show.

**I know why this error come becoz `Button` can declare in Activity and i'll use in `adapter.class` then the error can show but hot to i solve this**

how to use activity button in adapter android???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare button in `Activity`:

```
public static Button btnDownload;
```

in `onCreate`

```
btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
```

---

Now use this button reference in `Adapter`:

```
ActivityName.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

---

Now Simply copy and paste below code in your `Adapter` :

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    ActivityName.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

---

In `Adapter` class write below code:

Initialize Variable `checkBoxCount = 0;`

Now write below code :-

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    checkedBoxesCount++;
                else
                    checkedBoxesCount--;

                if(checkedBoxesCount > 0 ){
                    EquipmentDataActivity.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    EquipmentDataActivity.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please help me 1 other solution??

Comment: Ya please tell me @MohammadAli

Comment: how to Disable button after all check boxes are unchecked in adapter?

Comment: Welcome happy to help you :) @MohammadAli

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface that has the method getButton()
In adapter constructor pass that interface(this of the activity) and save it as local variable.
Instead btnDownload.setVisibility() do interface.getButton().setVisibility()
Your activity is implementing the interface

Comment: can you please provide me any example

Comment: passing button to recyclerview adapter is bad idea and it may cause memory leak

Comment: Not the button, just wanted to say: pass the interface reference

Answer (score 0):

passing button to recyclerview adapter is bad idea and it may cause memory leak

better thing to do is to set a callback to recyclerView winch when checkBox satte changed callback will be fired and in the callback you can change the visibility of the button

here is example :

Adapter  :

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
List<String> items=new ArrayList<>();

MyCallBack callBack;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(callBack!=null){
                callBack.onCheckBoxStateChanged(b);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


public void setCallBack(MyCallBack callBack) {
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

public interface MyCallBack {
    void onCheckBoxStateChanged(boolean newState);
}

    }
```

View Holder :

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
CheckBox checkBox;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chekcbox)
}
}
```

MyCallback :

```
public interface MyCallBack{
void onCheckBoxStateChanged(boolean newState);
}
```

Activity :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter();

    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);

    myAdapter.setCallBack(new MyAdapter.MyCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckBoxStateChanged(boolean newState) {

            if(newState)button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: @MohammadAli i edited my answer and added callback interface

Comment: @MohammadAli it means you not created instance of the adapter first call  MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(); then use setCallback

Comment: @MohammadAli that is related to your code logic ! you can use the counter in your callback and increase it when user checks the checkbox and decease when user unchecks the check box then you can check if the counter equals to 0 it means that all check boxes are unchecked !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173040/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-amir-hossein-mirzaei).

Comment: how to Disable button after all check boxes are unchecked?